# react: список из одного компонента не считается списком из одного компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Указываю структуру для главного компонента, который выводит дочерние компоненты, содержащую эти дочерние компоненты:

```
this.add_filters(
    <>
        <Filter1 />
    </>
);
```

метод `add_filters` выглядит так:

```
add_filters(filters: JSX.Element): void {

    console.log(filters.props.children.length);
}
```

Так во, когда указывается только один компонент, то функция `add_filters` выводит `undefined`, а когда указывается больше одного компонента, например

```
this.add_filters(
    <>
        <Filter1 />
        <Filter2 />
    </>
);
```

то выводится правильное кол-во компонент

соответственно и всякие методы для массивов типа `map` корректно работают

Подскажите, почему так происходит и как корректно тогда работать в ситуации, когда передается только 1 компонент

Comment: Пожалуйста прочтите это https://stackoverflow.com/a/66740808/2873538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так попробуйте:

```
function About() {
  function add_filters(filters) {
    if (Array.isArray(filters.props.children)) {
      console.log(filters.props.children.length); // Он имеет `length`
      filters.props.children.forEach((child) => {
        console.log(child);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(filters.props.children); // У этого нет `length`
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {add_filters(
        <>
          <div>Hi</div>
          <div>Bye</div>
        </>
      )}
      {add_filters(
        <>
          <div>Hey</div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Короче говоря, когда вы напишете это:

```
<>
  <div>Hi</div>
  <div>Bye</div>
</>
```

тогда `filters.props.children` - это массив

И, когда вы пишете:

```
<>
  <div>Hey</div>
</>
```

Тогда `filters.props.children` - это не массив, а  объект

Comment: да, точно! в итоге, чтобы учитывать все варианты пришлось написать такой код `const children = (Array.isArray(filters.props.children)) ? (filters.props.children) : (filters.props.children ? [filters.props.children] : []);`